# Libgdx How to set viewport position?

Tags: java, libgdx

I know that in libgdx a stage uses a viewport which defines the camera. I want to render a stage just on a small square on my screen. I tried using a customized viewport but I only managed to set it's size. I also tried using `setPosition(int screenX, int screenY)` method, but it seems that the viewport is always centered on the middle of the screen no matter what I try. Does anyone know how to set a viewport's position on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in my opinion is not in setting viewport position but in updating it - you've got to **center your camera** when viewport updating

```
    stage = new Stage();
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    viewport.setScreenPosition(500, 500); //I'm setting viewport's position

    ...

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) 
    {
        ...

        viewport.update(currentWindowWidth, currentWindowHeight, true); //here I'm updateing it with setting camera center

        ...
    }
```

Compare

```
void update(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, boolean centerCamera)
```

and

```
void update(int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
```

which calls the **update** version above with false as default

Comment: It seems indeed that I forgot to update... I had a feeling that I missed something. Just one more question: If I don't move the camera, is it enough to update the viewport just in the resize() method of the screen?

Comment: I would be keepeing it update in render (why not?) but try yourself ;)

Comment: I have encountered another issue. I thought that the setScreenPosition method of the viewport would allow me to move it anywhere, but it seems that no matter what value I enter, the viewport is being positioned at (0, 0). I don't know why this is happening. I am updating after every change.